# Etherbase ID changed after depositing funds to Mist wallet?

Tags: ether, mist

So it appears that my Mist wallet hadn't fully sync'd to a node, yet it produced a Etherbase ID for me to use.. I dumped the address into Kraken for a withdrawal, and realized after sending things over that the Mist wallet was still looking for peers.. I went to bed and let the wallet sync overnight. Upon waking up the Ether base ID has changed, and the funds aren't received from Kraken.. Are these funds lost forever or stuck somewhere I can get to?

Running Mist on Windows machine

Comment: Will any additional info help resolve this issue? With Mist installing Geth and Eth i'm hoping I can pull all the wallet addresses generated from the wallet and hopefully point the wallet to that address than the new wallet Mist changed to automatically upon sync to the network. Willing to tip Eth for assistance (additional for live help).

Comment: mist cant produce an id without you entering a passphrase. do you have backups of your keys? it's possible mist switched from geth to eth. did you check both clients balances?

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly search [ethchain.org](https://etherchain.org/) by address to find (or not find) the transaction record. Also check your ethereum wallet keystore directory - your key might be there (on mac Library/Ethereum/keystore). Good luck - hope it wasn't a large sum!

Comment: Thanks Ben, I have the full transaction record saved, so hopefully it won't be too much of a hassle to retrieve the ether once my wallet is pointing to the right spot.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, crisis averted... Whew..

What we ended up doing was uploading the key to https://www.myetherwallet.com/ then sending the funds back over to Kraken until my nerves settle, lol.

I did raise a comment with the Mist developer on the fact that many non devs may not have a need for such an easily accessible test area that could trigger more impatient folks than me to think their funds have vanished, when in reality they are parked in a key the wallet is not pointing to..

Lesson learned, and thank you everyone for your help.